# can not reverse ordering the array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

can not reverse array values in another array
please guide me how to inverse the array values in another array
i have used the swap method with a temp variable also, but it wasn't effective

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayHW {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("please enter the lenght of the array:");

        int len = in.nextInt();

        int k = 0 ;

        int[] array = new int [len];
        int[] invarr = new int[len];

        for( int i = 0; i < len ; i++ ){

        System.out.println("please enter the values:");
        array[i] = in.nextInt();
        }


        //using for loop
        for( int i=0 ; i < len ; i++ ){
            System.out.println("the array in normal case is:" + (i+1) + "\t" + array[i]);

        }

        /*for (int nav : array) {
            System.out.println(nav);
        }*/

        for( int i = len ; i >= 0 ; i--)
        {
            invarr[k] = array[i];
            System.out.println(invarr[k]);              
            k++;                
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The last available index of an array is `length-1`. So your last loop should be `for( int i = len-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)`

Comment: want to sort the array in some order or just want to reverse the order of array elements?

Comment: thanks a lot my friend its fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can use reverse method from Collections util class

```
List < Object > list = Arrays.asList(arr);
Collections.reverse(list);
Object[] res = list.toArray();
```

Comment: You don't need the last line. `arr` is reversed.

Comment: @aioobe What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that there's no need to use `list.toArray()` to get hold of the resulting array. `arr` itself is reversed. (Note though, that `arr` needs to have type `Integer[]` for this to work at all.)

Answer (score 3):

You may be experiencing `IndexOutofBoundException` because your loop to reverse the array starts with `i=len`. Arrays are traversed from `len-1` to `0`. So change your loop to:

```
for( int i = len -1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    invarr[k] = array[i];
    k++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reverse the array in this way

```
 int[] arr=new int[]{1,4,5,2};// index of this array are 0,1,2,3
 int[] reverseArr=new int[arr.length];
 int j=0;
 for(int i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--){ // considering arr from reverse order
     reverseArr[j]=arr[i];
     j++;
 }
```

Issue in your code

```
for( int i = len ; i >= 0 ; i--) // there is no index in array for i = len
```

Your for loop should be corrected as

```
for( int i = len-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should start from `len - 1`, because indexes are *zero based*. Change your last loop this way :

```
for( int i = len-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
    invarr[k] = array[i];
    System.out.println(invarr[k]);
    k++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: Thanks but this will help him to learn comparator too :) I will add that to my answer.

Comment: BTW, OP does not want to *sort* the array, OP wants to *reverse* the array.